# Regex to find name in salutation of an email

Tags: php, regex, parsing, email

I need to parse emails that follow the following format:

> Hi John Doe,
>   Here comes some more text.
>   And even more, and more, and more text.
>   Your user ID is: 1234
>   Your activation ID is: 5678910
>   Even more text comes here.

The Regex I am looking for have to return:

1. The name in the salutation (here: "John Doe")
2. The user ID (here: 1234)
3. The activation ID (here: 5678910)

I tried the following Regex but it returned the whole email; I believe the mistake I am making is that there are other commas in the rest of the email body, so the colon matches all of them. Even the name in the salutation can contain commas if the user entered a weird user name containing commas..

```
preg_match_all("/Hi (.*),/", $out, $match);
```

Comment: Off the top of my head - instead of `(.*)` try `(.+?)`.  Your current one is 'greedy'.

Comment: Hint: Use three regexes, one for `"Hi <name>,"`, one for `"Your user ID is: (\d+)"`, and one for `"Your activation ID is: (\d+)"`.

Answer (score 2):

Use regex pattern

```
/Hi (.*?),\n.*?user ID is: (\d+).*?activation ID is: (\d+)/s
      ↑                      ↑                         ↑
  "John Doe"              "1234"                   "5678910"
```

#### PHP code:

```
$pattern = '/Hi (.*?),\n.*?user ID is: (\d+).*?activation ID is: (\d+)/s';
preg_match($pattern, $email, $m);
print("$m[1]\n$m[2]\n$m[3]");
```

#### Output:

```
John Doe
1234
5678910
```

Check [**this demo**](http://ideone.com/86SGK).

Comment: I see you're shortening the regex... I prefer writing regexs as short as possible and rather use more regexs (of course there mustn't be any functionality penalty and this doesn't work for long text where each iteration trough complete text is expensive operation). I find long and complex regexs really hard to debug and analyse, trace "one subpatter changes" (if whole regex fails). Maybe you could mention named subpatters, they'd increase readability. (and I'd give you more voteups for work you're putting into this answer)

Comment: @Vyktor - For debugging you should use some tools and don't split single regex pattern into multiple patterns, as it hurts performance.

Comment: I'm well aware of the performance impact (I worked on data extraction from sites with really terrible html). That's why I mentioned that it shouldn't be done on long texts. Long regex = difficult readability, high performance. More short regexs = easy readability, worse performance. What you need differs from case to case I think. And for example he may need to keep script functional even if user id is not present... In that case this solution won't work (too bad he hasn't mention whether it should extract as much data as possible or everything or not at all).

Comment: This isn't working for me; the array containing the matches is empty. I found that the email uses HTML line breaks instead of the new line characters, so I assume that causes it not to work.

I tried to use only the first part: `$pattern = '/Hi (.*?),/s';` That works but it returns an array containing the following: `array ( 0 => 'Hi John Doe,', 1 => 'John Doe', )`

Answer (score 1):

I would use one Regex for each field:

```
$match = array();
$regexs = array(
    '~Hi\s+(.+?),~', // notice ? -> "greedy killer"
    '~Your user ID is: (\d+)~',
    '~Your activation ID is: (\d+)~')

if( !preg_match( $regexs[0], $text, $match)){
    throw new Exception('Invalid mail format, cannot find user name');
}

// .. and so on for each field
```

However you can put it all into one regexp (it will be better readable if you use [named subpattern](http://www.php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.recursive.php):

```
$regexp = '~Hi\s+(?P<name>.+?)|Your user ID is: (?P<id>\d+)|Your activation ID is: (?P<activation_id>\d+)~';
$matches = array();
preg_match_all( $regexp, $text, $matches, PREG_SET_ORDER);
foreach( $matches as $match){
    print_r( $match);
    if( !empty( $match['name'])){
       // Having a name
    }
}
```

Comment: This returns an empty array when I `var_export($matches)`